# Spark 2.2 Write Small number of files in each partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partition

I know there are lots of similar questions and answers in stackoverflow and other sites and I have gone through and tried every one of them but still I am not able to get what I want.

My source data has partitions on a day column and each partition has approximately 140 million records (2 GB appx).

Total records : 700 day_id partitions ( 2 years of data evenly distributed ) * 140 million = 98,000,000,000 records - 1.2 TB of data.

Source has 2000 - 3000 small files per partitions which is affecting cluster overall performance.

In target, I want to have not more than 10 files in each partition with sizes 100 mb to 600 mb.

My code : ( Max configuration I can afford for spark-submit is 100 executors with 5 cores each and 16gb each )

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.read.orc('/hdfs/path/for/source/data/')

#option-1 > with this I can achieve what I want but its awfully slow
df.repartition(8000,col("day_id")).write.mode('overwrite').option("maxRecordsPerFile", 500000).partitionBy("day_id").orc('/target/location/')

#option-2 > with this its faster but I end up with small files again
df.repartition(8000).write.mode('overwrite').option("maxRecordsPerFile", 500000).partitionBy("day_id").orc('/target/location/')

#option-3 > with this also its faster but I end up with small files again
df.repartition(8000,col("day_id"),rand(seed=100)).write.mode('overwrite').option("maxRecordsPerFile", 500000).partitionBy("day_id").orc('/target/location/')
```

If I dont use col("day_id") and use a small number in repartition eg. 10 or 20, then spark tries to fit the entire data into 20 partitions first and that fails.

Can you please suggest the best approach for this where I can have huge number of in-memory partitions which will give me huge number of workers but at the same time, each partitions wont have more than 5-10 day_ids , so that , I end up with 5-10 files in each partitions by those workers working on that partition.

Also, I learned that I can write my own partitioning function but I am not skilled enough to do that :(

Please let me know if I am not clear with my problem statement.

Comment: I am ashamed to ask that stupid question but I'm missing something : isn't the [first parameter of repartition function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition) the number of partitions that you want to have ? Then, if you see a lot of files isn't it because you asked to have 8,000 of them ? In my mind, there often one file created per partition (depending of what kind of persistence is used, of course).

Comment: @Rony Repartition 20 might be failing because the partition might not be able to hold x amount of data in 1 partition since that would come around 60GB per partition in spark's single executor memory based on the details in the question. Kindly try ```df.repartition(20,col("day_id")).write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy("day_id").orc('/target/location/')``` and let me know whether it fails or writes successfully in partitions with 20 file each partition.

Comment: @shrey I tried this. If I set repartition to 20 along with day_id, then spark will create spark.shuffle number of partitions in memory and ignore the 20, as it is less than the number of distict day ids available in the data.